# calculating row means for only rows that have more than one data point in R

Tags: r, missing-data

I am trying to calculate row means to create an average variable from 3 assessment points. I want to include cases that have 2 or 3 measurement points, but not those that have only one.

For example,

```
> a <- c(1,0,NA,1,NA,0,1,0,NA,0,NA)
> b <- c(1,0,NA,1,0,1,1,1,NA,0,1)
> c <- c(1,NA,NA,0,NA,0,1,1,1,0,0)
> mydata <- data.frame(a,b,c)
> mydata$M <- rowMeans(subset(mydata, select = c(1:3)), na.rm = TRUE)
> mydata$M
```

The current output produces a list of means for all the rows except one, which had 3 NAs:

```
[1] 1.00 0.00 NaN 0.66 0.00 0.33 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.00 0.50
```

However, my desired output would be:

```
[1] 1.00 0.00 NaN 0.66 NaN 0.33 1.00 0.66 NaN 0.00 0.50
```

Such that only rows with at least two data points would be used to calculate the mean, rather than returning the single data point as the row mean.

This is a complicated rule and I'm not sure how to define it. Any help would be appreciated.
(This is a data set with several thousand rows, so doing it manually is unthinkable!)

Thank you!
Sophie

Comment: You may use `ri <- rowSums(!is.na(mydata)) > 1` to get indices of rows with two or more non-`NA` values. Then calculate `rowMeans` and assign result at these indices: `mydata[ri , "m"] <- rowMeans(mydata[ri, ], na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a function that applies a mean to a row based on some condition. In your example, if there are two or more valid measurements, calculate mean.

```
a <- c(1,0,NA,1,NA,0,1,0,NA,0,NA)
b <- c(1,0,NA,1,0,1,1,1,NA,0,1)
c <- c(1,NA,NA,0,NA,0,1,1,1,0,0)
mydata <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Reading functions is best done from inside out. This one will take a vector `x` and see how many are *not* NA. When it sums (`sum`) the TRUE/FALSE values it turns them beforehand to 1 and 0, respectively. It then performs a test if there are more than 1 (so 2 or more) values - that are not NA.

```
conditionalMean <- function(x) {
  if (sum(!is.na(x)) > 1) {
    mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  } else {
    NA
  }
}
```

We apply this function to your `data.frame` row-wise, as denoted by `MARGIN = 1`. If you had a function that worked column-wise, you would use `MARGIN = 2`. You can try it out. Compare `apply(mydata, MARGIN = 2, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)` and `colMeans(mydata, na.rm = TRUE)`.

```
apply(mydata, MARGIN = 1, FUN = conditionalMean)

 [1] 1.0000000 0.0000000        NA 0.6666667        NA 0.3333333 1.0000000
 [8] 0.6666667        NA 0.0000000 0.5000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked perfectly. First exposure to functions in R.

Comment: @SophiaMagro in that case, see my edit. If you have more questions, feel free to ping me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  mutate(row_mean = ifelse((is.na(a)+is.na(b)+is.na(c)) %in% 2:3, NaN, 
                           rowMeans(.[1:3], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

**Result:**

```
    a  b  c  row_mean
1   1  1  1 1.0000000
2   0  0 NA 0.0000000
3  NA NA NA       NaN
4   1  1  0 0.6666667
5  NA  0 NA       NaN
6   0  1  0 0.3333333
7   1  1  1 1.0000000
8   0  1  1 0.6666667
9  NA NA  1       NaN
10  0  0  0 0.0000000
11 NA  1  0 0.5000000
```